# Prevent showing "out of stock" products as "related products" in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, hide

Any one knows how to prevent showing "out of stock"-products as "related product" in Magento?

If you deactivate a product it won't show, but i need it to disappear from "related products" when it is sold out as well.

Thanks

Comment: There mightbe a problem with ur inventory settings..Check it out.. MAgento doesnt show out of stock any where if u set display to NO.

Comment: Display is set to YES, because I want products to show in the catalog also when they are out of stock, however on a normal product page the "buy now" button don't show on these products. In the related products the "buy now" button did show, which causes people being able to click the button - and the get an error msg that it is sold out. My solution for this problem was however to add a <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?> on the "buy now" button, so that the button is replaced with an "Out of stock" message when the item is sold out.

Answer (score 1):

Out of stock products in general do not shows up in the related product blocks, i have just tested this on my local installation.

Please check following thing while editing a product.

On Inventory tab :

Manage Stock : Yes
Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock : 0
Stock Availability : In stock

Thus when the last item of a product is purchased magento automatically set its status to Out of stock.

Comment: Even if the product is Out of stock, it still displays as related product in frontend. It's ok that the product shows in catalog when Out of stock (since it will be in stock later), but when it is Out of stock right now, I don't want it to display as related product. Is there a solution for that?